# How to show pop up menu from database in gridview on each gridview row items?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to show pop up menu from database in gridview on each gridview row items ?

Example of this is :

http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SelectBus.aspx?fromCityId=733&fromCityName=Delhi&toCityId=757&toCityName=Manali&doj=26-Dec-2010&busType=Any

Move your cursor to Departure time and arrival time...a want this type of popup in gridview items....which fetch entries from database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with javascript/jQuery. The gridview itself has nothing to do with this.
If I was going to build what he has just by looking at it I would create the table dynamically. This way you could use a string builder and insert variable names in between each td tag. You retrieve all your data from the database and store in a List or even better use LINQ to SQL.

I wish I could give you a sample in VB, but here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StoreDataContext db = new StoreDataContext();
    var join = from b in db.Brands      
               select new
               {
                   Brand = b,

                   c = b.Description.Length < 204 ? b.Description : b.Description.Substring(0, 204) + "...",
                   Sources = 
                        from s in db.Sources
                        join xref in db.Brands_Sources on s.SourceID equals xref.SourceID
                        where xref.BrandID == b.BrandID
                        select s       
               };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append( "<table class='tableStripe'>");
    sb.Append( "<tr><th width='1%'>Active</th><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Short Description</th><th>Source</th><th width='1%'>Date Created</th><th width='1%'>Data Modified</th></tr>");

    foreach (var result in join)
    {
        string chk = (result.Brand.Active ? "checked='checked'" : "");
        sb.AppendFormat( "<tr><td><input class='brandChk' value='{4}' type='checkbox' {0}></td><td width='1%'><img width='50px' src='{1}'</img></td>" +
                "<td><a href='/admin/Catalog/Brand/Detail.aspx?brandId={4}'>{2}</a></td><td width='60%'>{3}</td>", chk, result.Brand.Image, result.Brand.Name, result.c,result.Brand.BrandID);
        sb.Append("<td>");
            foreach (var q in result.Sources)
            {
                string srcname = (q.Source1=="Motovicity" ? "Motovicity":"Direct");
                sb.AppendFormat("<img src='{0}' title='{1}'</img>", q.Image,srcname);
            }
            string date = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", result.Brand.DateCreated);
            string mod = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", result.Brand.DateModified);

        sb.Append("</td>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", date, mod);
    }
    sb.Append("</table>");
    resultSpan.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
}
```

As you can see I code the html for a checkbox and insert the brand id into the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

He is not fetching record on runtime basically if you see the structure he has the information in the tooltip attribute of anchor tag and using jquery cluetip to display it.

so you can use any jquery tooltip plugin to display same as he is doing.

Thanks