# list view problem with respect to my problem

Tags: c#, .net

I have a listview in wpf and i am swapping two items index..

the swapping must be visible to the user.

i tried giving thread delay..

it didnt work

How to do that..

Comment: What do you mean by "the swapping must be visible to the user"?

Comment: are you using web forms? You can't use C# to do this, you need to use javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I'm afraid he's using WinForms :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was going to do this I would delete the list view and lock it up where you can't use it again. Then code whatever your list view was outputting in C# using whatever you use to query your database(I think LINQ to SQL is the most robust solution right now) and then use a string builder to construct the html. This way you can assign a id to each div and append an incrementing number to the end of the id. Finally you could write your javascript and use the id's. Here is a link that shows how to build a gridview without using a gridview control.

See the first answer to the question in this link: [How to show pop up menu from database in gridview on each gridview row items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362863/how-to-show-pop-up-menu-from-database-in-gridview-on-each-gridview-row-items/4362889#4362889)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will work for your problem or not.

I think you need some kind of animation there. If it is web project, you can use jQuery animation to do that.